# Objective-C implicit conversion of obj-c pointer to autoreleasing id<protocol> error

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, automatic-ref-counting, implicit-conversion

I'm having a very specific problem, I'm working with a DAO (data access object) that takes varius states, these states are passed into an init method and are then used.

Now the problem that I'm having is that I can't seem to pass a concrete state into the `init` method, I always get an

> implicit conversion of an objective-c pointer to __autoreleasing id is disallowed with ARC

The code:

```
-(DAOObject *)makeSpecificDataAccessObject{
    SQLiteState* localstate = [[SQLiteState alloc] initWithTableName:@"TableName"];
    DAOObject* specificDAO = [[DAOObject alloc] initWithLocalState:localstate]; //where error happens
    return specificDAO;
}

@interface DAOObject : NSObject <SettingsListenerProtocol>
    -(id)initWithLocalState:(id<StateProtocol> *)LocalState;
@end

@interface SQLiteState : NSObject <StateProtocol>
-(id)initWithTableName:(NSString *)tableName;

@end
```

Answer (score 16):

Remove the star `*` in

```
-(id)initWithLocalState:(id<StateProtocol> *)LocalState;
```

`id` is already defined as a *pointer* to an instance of a class.

Comment: thanks! good to know, searched all over the internet and didn't find anything.

Comment: Frankly, I'd consider redeclaring that as `(NSObject<StateProtocol>*)` (or declaring that `<StateProtocol>` also includes the `<NSObject>` protocol.   The reality is that *everything is an NSObject* these days and it is easier to embrace that than the very narrow definition implied by `(id <SomeProtocol>)`.

Comment: @bbum: Using `id` for protocols seems to be widely spread (`id<UITableViewDataSource>`, `id<UITableViewDelegate>` ...), so that I have also adopted it in my code without thinking too much about it. Would using `NSObject *` for protocols be better programming style?

Comment: I lean to the latter as it is more locally indicative of what the object can do.   Note that `UITableViewDataSource` and most other `UI*` protocols conform to `NSObject`.   So, when defining a protocol, you should generally do the same.  I prefer the local declaration of `NSObject<P>*` over `id<P>` for local self-documentation.